# Parse json returned from API

Tags: php

API returns following json.

```
$jsonData = '{"ResponseCode":200, "ResponseDetail":"Success", "AccessToken":"kksjfdlk"}{"ResponseCode":400, "ResponseDetail":"False"}';
```

How can I access value for `ResponseCode`?

Comment: *to filter through* - what are you trying to filter?

Comment: i'm trying to output a ResponseCode $json = json_decode($jsonData); $json->ResponseCode;

Comment: Question was too broad and was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that the posted string is NOT valid JSON you can extract `ResponseCode` values using `preg_match_all` function:

```
$jsonData = '{"ResponseCode":200, "ResponseDetail":"Success", "AccessToken":"kksjfdlk"}{"ResponseCode":400, "ResponseDetail":"False"}';

preg_match_all("/\"ResponseCode\"\s?:\s?(\d+)/", $jsonData, $m);
$response_codes = [];

// if there are matches
isset($m[1]) && $response_codes = $m[1];
print_r($response_codes);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 200
    [1] => 400
)
```